# Configure mounting timeout at boot

Tags: boot, mount, nfs

On remotely rebooting a 12.04 machine I found it hanging at the "unable to mount soandso: Skip, Manual Abort? " (That's pretty much how I remember the message) The machine was basically stopped there until I hooked up a keyboard and pressed "s". I can see the rationale for the question, but I'd really like to know where to configure it or turn it off altogether. A mandatory question like this makes sense in a desktop environment but for servers I'd like more flexibility.
So where do I fiddle and tweak this?

Comment: check your settings in /etc/fstab

Comment: may this helps http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29196/automount-nfs-autofs-timeout-settings-for-unreliable-servers-how-to-avoid-han

Answer (score 11):

Now it is 2020 and this question can be updated to represent current status. In a nutshell, the timeout can be set by using `x-systemd.mount-timeout` parameter:

From [manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/systemd.mount.5.html):

> Mount units may either be configured via unit files, or via /etc/fstab (see fstab(5) for
> details). Mounts listed in /etc/fstab will be converted into native units dynamically at
> boot and when the configuration of the system manager is reloaded. In general, configuring
> mount points through /etc/fstab is the preferred approach.

and:

> x-systemd.mount-timeout=
> Configure how long systemd should wait for the mount command to finish before giving
> up on an entry from /etc/fstab. Specify a time in seconds or explicitly append a unit
> such as "s", "min", "h", "ms".

Thus, for example:

```
/dev/sdc     /mnt/backupdir     ext4     defaults,x-systemd.mount-timeout=30 0 2
```

waits atmost for 30 seconds during the boot for that entry to be mount before give up.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the hint with the console message; it saved me having to plug-in a monitor to the console of a test server (keyboard sufficed...)

That said, up to at least 14.04, Ubuntu supported a `nobootwait` option for fstab entries, which would achieve what you want; smth like this:

```
UUID=8b481900-fb7a-4e9e-929c-e940a6b913a4 /data   ext4   nobootwait  0  2
```

Alas as mentioned in [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786928/ubuntu-16-04-fstab-fails-with-nobootwait), the `nobootwait` option was removed in 16.04 with currently no viable substitute other than the `/etc/rc.local` workaround described in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the mount by editing or commenting it out in `/etc/fstab` and replace it with an explicit `mount` command in `/etc/rc.local`.